# Angular skipLocationChange doesn't work with resolver

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular10, angular-resolver

I am using a resolver   resolve: `{ deviceView: DeviceViewResolverService }` , in order to get all necessary data for my component before it is initialized.

I also use highcharts and if I call the same URL but want to get a different data from backend, I used  `this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: false }).then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(uri));` such that an empty URL will be used before I go to the same URL for highcharts.

Now it seems not to work, and the HTTP calls are canceled before the component is initialized and the router state stays at '/'.

I don't understand what can I do to fix it ??

EDIT

it seems not to wok only if I use '/' to navigate, but with other paths which are not empty, it works just fine, but one can see the first page and then is navigated to the right one...